# How to disable auto publish in AKS sitecore 10.3

Tags: azure, aks

By default, auto publishing is enabled in the environment. Auto publish needs to disable before deployment and enable after the deployment in the AKS Sitecore 10.3 environment. How to achieve this?
Please help me.

Comment: You want to disable publishing or the auto-publish via workflow or some other trigger?

Comment: Auto publish via pipeline during the code deployment

Comment: Are you deploying your own container images to Azure Kubernetes (AKS)? Or is this a managed solution somehow? If indeed AKS you should have full control over what config is baked into image. Also, when deploying a new CM pod, publishing wouldnt be available. Please can you expand your question with more details of your exact setup.